New filters for the question page and some homepage odds & ends
Over the next few days, we will be rolling out some additional filter options on the Stack Overflow Questions page. This is a result of the feedback that was received on the original homepage post. Some of these question filter options were on the homepage but now reside on the Questions page.
New Filters

Trending: This is identical to the previously named hot option.
Week: Content posted in the last seven days.
Month: Content posted in the last thirty days.


New sort by & filter by options
We have added some new “Sorted By” and “Filter By” options:

Trending: Sorts by recent activity and volume of activity.
Most Activity: This sorting option can be used to sort questions by the highest volume of activity.
Post Date: This field can be used to look for questions posted since a specified date.


RSS feeds moved to profile settings
Previously, you could find some RSS feed options at the bottom of the right sidebar, depending on what question filters you applied to the homepage. Those RSS feed options can now be found in your profile settings under Settings>RSS feeds.

Recently Viewed Posts
As we mentioned in some of our previous homepage communication, we have introduced a Recently Viewed Posts feature on the bottom of the right sidebar. There, you can now find posts you have visited recently, where you can follow them, and see the vote and answer counts.
Let us know if you have any questions or feedback on these changes. We will be monitoring this post for feedback until December 23rd, 2024.

"RSS feeds moved to profile settings" Oh good, another feature I need to wait 23+ seconds to access.

@ThomA Step 1. Make the feature exceptionally obtuse to access; Step 2. Remove the feature citing low usage.

I like the Recently Viewed Posts feature! Thank you.

Ahh, so saves, flag history, followed posts, etc are all on the "list" too, @VLAZ .

Yeah, I "think" I quite like the 'Recently Viewed Posts' feature also but can't help wondering how it will be implemented...: Will 'Staging Ground' Posts also "count"...? Either opened from the 'SG' main-page, the 'Questions'-page or the 'Homepage'...? Same with Posts opened from one of the Review Queues...? Or from a User's Profile...? Or from a Link from a 'Meta'-Thread...? Will (in the meantime) deleted Threads still remain as an entry in that list...? (Best would be if all those "categories" or possible origins would be configurable with Checkboxes if we want to include them or not...)

Don't get me wrong, the stuff you suggest here isn't bad, but moving around a few links and adding filter options adresses only a tiny part of the overwhelmingly negative feedback in the previous thread. Somehow you, or other staff, didn't respond to any of the feedback in over 1.5 months. What's the point of feedback threads if you handle it that way

@chrki that is what I consider to be the other meta effect. Meta is very negative and quite confrontational in how it presents its disagreements and concerns. Overwhelming is the right choice of words. ... we miss Shog, to be honest. Someone who has mastered the art of diplomacy.

questions receive one initial look from me. if they don't catch my interest then, that's too bad. if they do, they get followed and go into a bookmark folder for revisiting. I have no use for "trending" or "activity" (identical?). an asker moves on after the first answer. adding a better answer is all but worthless in any niche tag. -- this whole thing reminds me of at least one episode of MASH where they have to spruce up the camp in fake and ridiculous ways for some visiting dignitary. only difference here: no dignitaries coming to visit. it's just "let's change it up a little".

@chivracq Staging Ground questions will not be included in the recently viewed posts, nor will posts from the review queue unless you go to the actual question. Otherwise, any other question you look at should show up there. Good feedback on the check box options, I will bring it back to the team.

@chrki I would not call this the last of the changes made there. This is just the first set of public ones we have been able to made after cleaning up some bugs, etc. There will likely be more changes in the future.

Oh..., nice about the Feedback, Thanks... Well, about the Checkbox options for 'Recently Viewed Posts', the page for 'Proposed questions' in the 'Staging Ground' has been nicely implemented, with the 'Status' + 'Post attributes' DDLB's containing each multiple separately checkable options, translating to &statusFilter=new%2creeval%2cmajor%2cminor%2cinactive%2cskipped%2cpublished%2cofftopic%2cduplicate&col=LastActivity&dir=Descending in the URL, => maybe an idea to reuse that functionality/implementation. The more control/granularity/configurability we have as Users = the better...!

Hum, stg else, quite a few of the 'Filter & Sort' options could use a mini-Help-Popup explaining what they mean exactly: Post date (=> older than 3d/up to 3d old/exactly from 3d ago...?) + Last activity (=> Edit (Qt and/or Answer?)/Answer added/Comment...?) + Most frequent (had always wondered what it meant, only understood today thanks to Lundin's Comment) + Trending + Most activity (=> Views/Edits (Qt and/or Answer?)/Answers added/Comments...?)...

I like the 'Recently Viewed Posts' feature. Currently it is the only reason I would want go to the home page. The only problem is the we will need to scroll over a bunch of ads to get there, since ads in home page is not disabled by the reduce ads privilege. This makes it hard to discover that this feature even exists.

That drop-down menu is a little confusing.

What does "Frequent" mean? "Frequently sees activity"? "Frequently visited"? Something else? Even if it may seem obvious, it could be good to clarify.
I imagine "CUSTOM FILTERS" is supposed to be a heading, but it looks just like another menu item with inconsistent casing. Could be good to find other ways to distinguish it, like making the font size slightly smaller, a different font, different shade of gray, or something.
It's weird to have sorts and ordering clumped together. If I select "week", then sure, I'll only see questions from the current week, but how will they be ordered? What if I want to see "frequent" questions from this week, or trending questions from this month?

I feel like it would make more sense to have "week" and "month" in it's own section, so I can select both an order and a filter.
Something like this:
Frequent whatever-this-is
Score
Trending
---
Week
Month
All
---
Unanswered (my tags)
---
CUSTOM FILTERS
New Python

Edit:
Thanks @VLAZ for pointing out that none of this is new, so everything said here is probably out-of-scope. But I'll leave the answer here as it's still valid feedback on the existing design that could still be done as a sort of "stretch" goal, or in the future. Or not.

"What does "Frequent" mean?" that is not a new option. "I imagine "CUSTOM FILTERS" is supposed to be a heading, but it looks just like another menu item with inconsistent casing." also not new. "It's weird to have sorts and ordering clumped together." also not new.

Frequent was always around and was never quite useful. It means frequently referred to. Each time a post gets linked to by another SO post or used as a dupe target, it's "frequent" counter goes up by one. A more useful feature would have been to instead only show posts frequently used as dupe targets.

"could still be done as a sort of "stretch" goal, or in the future" we can't even get formerly existing features to be included as "stretch goals" when one of these redesigns chops off some functionality.
